# nextjs webpack typescript (.ts, .tsx) Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

My `next.config.mjs`:

```
export default {
  webpack: (config) => {
    // Find rules that includes current directory
    const rulesWithCurrentDir = config.module.rules.filter((rule) => rule.include && rule.include.includes(__dirname))
    // Prepare the sibling package paths that we want to include
    const apiPath = path.resolve(`${__dirname}../../api`)
    const siblingPackagePaths = [apiPath]
    // Push sibling package paths
    rulesWithCurrentDir.forEach((ruleWithCurrentDir) => ruleWithCurrentDir.include.push(...siblingPackagePaths))
    return config
  },
}
```

`babel.config.mjs`:

```
export default {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", '@babel/preset-typescript', "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: [
    [
      'babel-plugin-transform-imports',
      {
        lodash: {
          transform: 'lodash/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/material': {
          transform: '@mui/material/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/icons-material': {
          transform: '@mui/icons-material/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/lab': {
          transform: '@mui/lab/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
<snip>
}
```

`yarn build` error I bump into:

```
../api/src/components/ModelAutocompleteField.tsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { AutocompleteProps, CircularProgress, TextField, TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material'
| 
> export interface OptionType {
|   id: string
|   title?: string
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when your Next.js project is not aware of existence of TypeScript files. It does this by checking if `tsconfig.json` is present in the root directory of the project i.e. besides `next.config.js` or `next.config.mjs` file. If the `tsconfig.json` is somewhere else then you must [manually configure](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript) it.

Comment: `tsconfg.json` is there.